# Size of the instances depends on their position

Tags: transforms, geometry-nodes, instances

I need to make some changes to this leaf generator. The size of the leaves should vary depending on the height. This means that the upper leafs should be smaller than the lower ones.

[image]
[image]

[image]
(Blender v 3.2.1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a *Position* node and get the Z value with a *Separate XYZ* node, then use a *Map Range* to fit the output values to input range and plug it into *Scale* on the *Instance on Points* node.

By the way, it took me a while to figure out some values on the *Map Range* node. Your "Cube" object has a scale of 0.037, it's always better to apply the scale with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> before creating the *Geometry Nodes*. If for any reason you cannot work on without applying the scale, then your plant will "explode" into a gigantic mess once you do that.

[image: scale by Z height]